# mod_rewrite for wildcard subdomains

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need help in writing a mod_rewrite to allocate users their own personal subdomains.

I want to convert sub.domain.com to sub.domain.com/profile?user=sub

but if user opens any page the 'user' variable should also be passed i.e.

sub.domain.com/page  to  sub.domain.com/page?user=sub

It should be masked i.e. no redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root

```
# for / requests
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
# this step may not be necessary if you don't care about "www.domain.conm"
RewriteCond %1 !www
RewriteRule ^$ /profile?user=%1 [QSA,L]

# for any "page"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
# this step may not be necessary if you don't care about "www.domain.conm"
RewriteCond %1 !www
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?user=%1 [QSA,L]
```